how to customize big chart font color?
For the big number chart (Apache Superset version 3.1.3), cannot find a way to customize the font color. Only the font size can be changed in the chart option.
Also, tried to use the dashboard edit CSS to customize the specific char header color and it does not work either. Here is one of the example CSS tried:
#chart-id-216 .header-line
{
    color: red;
}

Is there a way to customize the font color? It would be very useful if it can be done as part of the chart option.
